# Configuring OWIN on SSRS Portal

Tags: asp.net, owin, ssrs-2016

I'm attempting to implement custom security for an SSRS2016 box. I have done this successfully in the past with asp.net forms authentication. In this scenario, I need to read and authenticate from an OWIN cookie. I can do this successfully in a test rig hosted in IIS, but when I move the code to the SSRS web host, the OWIN startup class is not called.
Is there a way to configure the SSRS portal to bootstrap the OWIN settings?